# can urlclassloader and system.load work together?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, classloader

Is it possible to work with urlclassloader and system.load at a time?
I am writing a class

```
class A
{
  public loadlibrary()
{
 System.load(somedllwithpath);
}
}
```

and loading that class A in my application using URLClassloader. Now when I am calling a native method that belongs to that dll, it is giving unsatisfiedlinkerror. Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: Please show the full error message and stack trace. The format of UnsatisfiedLinkError message can give clues on the problem. Also, please indicate which operating system you're using, and show the value of `somedllwithpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed the dll at the specified path in your system?

The dll is not downloaded with URLClassloader, you must install it in some other way.

Comment: The dll is in the path and as per java documentation System.load() can load the dll from the specified path. But here when i am loading the wrapper class using URLClassloader, that time the problem is coming.